# How to find the web part: Error while executing web part: System.StackOverflowException: Operation caused a stack overflow

Tags: 2010, web-part

> uls ERROR: Error while executing web part: System.StackOverflowException: Operation caused a stack overflow.

How can I find out which web part is throwing this error?

[This is not the kind of StackOverflow I like :)]

Comment: You should debug your code, seems like some sort of recursion spinning out of control. Without seeing your actual code it is impossible to help you

Comment: If you get this on a page, you can go to the address of the page but append `?contents=1` to the URL. This will take you to a list of all webparts added to the page. From here you can close them one by one to see which one causes the error

Comment: I don't know the page. The error appears in the ULS logs.

Comment: There should be a get request for a page in close relation to the error message in the ULS

Answer (score 0):

You should open web part maintenance page. (appending query string `contents=1`)

Then remove all web parts, then add one by one. This way you can find which webpart is causing the issue.